# ADA: GNAT on Android

Tags: android, ada

I have managed to install [GNAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNAT) on my OS X system, but now I would like to install it on my Android mobile phone in order to code... In my bed! Or in order to do homework while walking around the campus without having to unpack my [MacBook Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro) from my backpack.

So I searched Android Terminal in [Google Play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play) and now that I have it, I tried the "Fetch" command, but it is not found. I would like to be able to write my ADA codes in a text application and compile them on the phone (to see if they are well written). I do really newbie stuff such as prime number and maths problem.

The tutorial seems to be there, but I don't understand it: [DragonLace.Net](http://www.dragonlace.net)

Comment: That tutorial is for installing a cross-compiler, that lets you work on a PC running FreeBSD or similar, to create programs running on your Android device. Not a compiler that compiles your source on Android. I believe there is a project to develop a native Android compiler but I don't know any details.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I wille try to install GNAT on android when I'll i get better in programming and computer sciences. Have a nice day.

Comment: Android is not a native platform for GNAT.  http://www.adacore.com/gnatpro/platforms

Comment: If I’d noticed that the q was originally asked in 2014 I wouldn’t have tried to answer it. This is a classic XY problem, OP wants to program using their phone, thinks they have to install the compiler on their phone, should be using an online compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have done it is with [Andronix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=studio.com.techriz.andronix), which is not exactly a virtual machine, but you can run some distributions with limitations, on [Termux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termux).

1. First install [Termux](https://f-droid.org/es/packages/com.termux/) from [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/es/) (not [Google Play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play)).
2. Then install [Andronix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=studio.com.techriz.andronix),
3. There you install a distribution that runs GNAT on Termux, following the documentation or videos on YouTube.
4. On Termux, you type `./start-the_os_you_installed.sh` in order to run the Linux system.
5. You install GNAT like if you would be on a Linux machine. The compilations will be like in a Linux machine as well.

It works on [Ubuntu 22.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_22.04_LTS_(Jammy_Jellyfish)) (Jammy Jellyfish). You have to have to access to the distribution on Termux every time you want to compile an Ada file. You will need a code editor. It can be from the Google Play (I don't know any editor compatible with Ada) or from Termux, like [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29), [Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs), etc.